# Python: access to object attribute from callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to design class with callback function which is transferred to some C library. Need to grant access to object of this class without changing callback arguments. How to do this?

```py
from ctypes import *
...
lib = CDLL('mylibname.so')
    ...
    class A(object):
        def __init__(self):
            CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_uint32, c_void_p)
            self.callback_func = CALLBACK(A.message_callback)
            self.param = None
        def message_callback(data):
            ... #here need access to self.param
            return 0
        def set_param(self, param):
            self.param = param
    ...
    a = A()
    lib.lib_func(param1, param2, a.callback_func)
```

**EDIT:**
I've changed callback method in the class with wrapper function:

```py
from ctypes import *
...
lib = CDLL('mylibname.so')

class struct_t(Structure):
    pass
struct_t._fields_ = [('next', POINTER(value_pair_t)),
                         ('key', c_char_p),
                         ('value', c_char_p)]
...
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.param = None

    def wrapper(self):
        CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_uint32, POINTER(struct_t))
        def message_callback(data):
            ... # now I have access to self here
            return 0
        return CALLBACK(message_callback)

    def set_param(self, param):
        self.param = param
...
a = A()
lib.lib_func(param1, param2, a.wrapper())
```

It works in python2, but I still have issues with python3:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 260, in 'calling callback function'
TypeError: 'LP_struct_t' object is not callable

Here is link with same issue: [Weird bug?](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ctypes/4785)

Comment: Why would you create a closure to access `self`? Just use a method as the callable, as I showed you.

Comment: Your edit here also has a potential problem. The callable you pass to the C library only exists until `lib_func` returns. Then it will be garbage collected, deallocating the thunk code and data. If the thunk code still exists to call [`closure_fcn`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c3896275c0f6/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c#l315), then who knows what garbage `p->callable` points to. Apparently in this case it's the `LP_struct_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define `message_callback(self, data)` and use `self.callback_func = A.CALLBACK(self.message_callback)`. Note I used `A.CALLBACK`. Set it as a class attribute. Defining it for each instance is a waste of time.

For example:

C:

```
typedef int (*callback_t)(void *data);

int test(const char *data, callback_t f) {
    f((void *)data); 
    return 0;
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *

class A(object):
    CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_uint32, c_void_p)

    def __init__(self):        
        self.callback_func = A.CALLBACK(self.message_callback)
        self.param = None

    def message_callback(self, data):
        self.param = cast(data, c_char_p).value
        return 0
```

Demo:

```
>>> lib = CDLL('./lib.so')
>>> a = A()
>>> lib.test.argtypes = [c_char_p, A.CALLBACK]
>>> lib.test("updated", a.callback_func)
0
>>> a.param
'updated'
```