# Python-GStreamer: Access class members inside callback function with fixed arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I have a callback, that is provided by GStreamer-Python bindings which accepts fixed number of arguments. Here is the API : [add_probe](https://valadoc.org/gstreamer-1.0/Gst.Pad.add_probe.html)
I call this function from inside a class function. Below is the pesudo code:

```
class Example:
   def __init__(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        thread.start()

   def run(self):
        #if external event
        self.idsrcpad = identity.get_static_pad("src")  #get source pad 
        self.idsrcpad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.IDLE,self.modify_pipeline)


   def modify_pipeline(pad,info,self):
        #access self.idsrcpad
        self.idsrcpad.unlink(...)
```

Accessing `self.idsrcpad`, gives an error saying that  `idsrcpad` is not a member of self.

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377429/python-access-to-object-attribute-from-callback) addresses, a similar issue, but then the callback function in the question does not have fixed number of arguments. In my case, the arguments are fixed for the callback function. Here is a more elaborate description of the [add_probe](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstPad.html#gst-pad-add-probe) function.

Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for the callback is :

```
 def modify_pipeline(self,pad,info):
```

With this new definition, `self` can be used inside the function.